# Basic understanding of AudioRecording

Tags: android, audio-recording

I have a problem calculating the time for each frame when recording using AudioRecord. So if someone can be a bro and explain the basics that would be greatly appreciated.

What does the following mean?

- sampleRate - is it the number of bytes you have given as a sample? or the number of bytes that becomes a sample to be checked with AudioRecord
- FFT - in simple terms what does it mean?
- How do you calculate time? do you calculate it by the buffersize / frameByteSize?

Referring to an example code copied from Jacquet Wong

```
public class RecorderThread extends Thread {

private AudioRecord audioRecord;
private boolean isRecording;
private int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
private int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
private int sampleRate = 44100;
private int frameByteSize = 2048; // for 1024 fft size (16bit sample size)
byte[] buffer;

public RecorderThread(){
    int recBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding); // need to be larger than size of a frame
    audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleRate, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, recBufSize);
    buffer = new byte[frameByteSize];
}

public AudioRecord getAudioRecord(){
    return audioRecord;
}

public boolean isRecording(){
    return this.isAlive() && isRecording;
}

public void startRecording(){
    try{
        audioRecord.startRecording();
        isRecording = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stopRecording(){
    try{
        audioRecord.stop();
        isRecording = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public byte[] getFrameBytes(){
    audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, frameByteSize);

    // analyze sound
    int totalAbsValue = 0;
    short sample = 0; 
    float averageAbsValue = 0.0f;

    for (int i = 0; i < frameByteSize; i += 2) {
        sample = (short)((buffer[i]) | buffer[i + 1] << 8);
        totalAbsValue += Math.abs(sample);
    }
    averageAbsValue = totalAbsValue / frameByteSize / 2;

    //System.out.println(averageAbsValue);

    // no input
    if (averageAbsValue < 30){
        return null;
    }

    return buffer;
}

public void run() {
    startRecording();
}
```

}

Sorry, I am not an easy learner for audio recording. I can't seem to make it click yet. Hope you guys can enlighten me with this questions.

Comment: "Sampling rate" almost always refers to [the number of samples per unit of time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_rate). The greater the number of samples, the larger the recording but the higher the quality (to greatly generalize). The 44.1kHz sample rate in your code is the standard sampling rate for CDs.